# pandas: replace with a dictionary does not work with string of sentences

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, replace

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['Lary Page is visiting today',' His boss, Maria Jackson is here.']})
```

I have extracted the names in the list below. and used faker library to create fake names equal to the len of the person_name list, and created a dictionary out of the lists.

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

person_name = ['Lary Page', 'Maria Jackson']
fake_name= [fake.name() for n in range(len(person_name))]
name_dict = dict(zip(person_name, fake_name ))
```

now I would like to replace them in the dataframe using the dictionary, but it returns an error.

```
df.text.str.replace(name_dict)
```

my desired output:(e.g)

```
print(df)

Angela Mindeston is visiting today
His boss, Emanuel Smith is here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use callback with lambda for [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) or [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
regex = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in name_dict.keys())
df['text1'] = df.text.str.replace(regex, lambda x: name_dict[x.group()], regex=True)

df['text2'] = df.text.replace(name_dict, regex=True)
print (df)
                                text                                 text1  \
0        Lary Page is visiting today            Gary Cox is visiting today   
1   His boss, Maria Jackson is here.   His boss, Mr. George Jones is here.   

                                  text2  
0            Gary Cox is visiting today  
1   His boss, Mr. George Jones is here.
```